# Centralize .ssh/authorized_file amonst many linux servers

Tags: linux, ssh, login, password, root

We have many Linux servers. The requirement is all Linux servers log in into each other password-less with root user.

The problem is if a server is added / removed / reinstalled its SSH key needs to be added in all other servers.

So is it possible to centralize it.

What I have thought is to create a file on a centralized location, modify it as per needed and then create a cronjob in all servers to get that file periodically.

Any better ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want setup an authentication server like [Kerberos](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-kerberos-workstation-auth) to securely authenticate the rest servers. The main idea is you just login into one server to obtain a ticket and that ticket could be used by all of your servers. OpenSSH can do this automatically with Kerberos.

[image: Diagram of How SSH and Kerberos Works]
<sup>*Credit to: https://www.confluent.io/*</sup>

There are several good guides to achieve this:

- [Kerberos Installation Guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-kerberos-workstation-auth)
- [Using OpenSSH with Kerberos](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=support-using-openssh-kerberos)